# AsyncTask: Why is the XML file not being read?

Tags: android

The following is my code. XMLfunctions reads the XML file and stores it in `String xml`. I had to use AsyncTask as I got a NetworkOnMainThreadException. However I'm not sure of how to do it and am messing it up somewhere.

```
package foo.bar.quux;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class XMLfunctions {


    int numResults;
    NodeList nodes;
    Document doc;
    static ServiceTasks task;
    String line;
    public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){

        Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;

    }


     private class ServiceTasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {

                            try {

                                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/example.xml");

                                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                                    line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                    line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                    line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
                                }
                            return null;


            }


        } 

     public String getXML(){     

         return line;
    }

     public void executeXML(){
         task = new ServiceTasks();
         task.execute();
     }


}
```

The methods `executeXML()` and `getXML()` are called in another activity :

```
  public class Main extends ListActivity {

         String xml;
         static XMLfunctions funct;
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.listofcategories);
            funct = new XMLfunctions();
            funct.executeXML();
            xml = funct.getXML();
.
.
.
}
```

However xml seems to be null even after `executeXML` is called as I get a `NullPointerException`. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not get the results until the AsyncTask is done.

So, even though, the control is moved to the line `xml = funct.getXML();`, and this line is executed, this does not mean that the AsyncTask is done.

Your results will be available when `doInBackground` returns and in your AsyncTask override the function `onPostExecute` and report results back to the caller.

Implement a listener in such a way:

```
package foo.bar.quux;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class XMLfunctions {

    public interface ListenerToXML {
            public void AsyncTaskDone();
    }
    ListenerToXML mListener;
    public void setListener(ListenerToXML listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
    int numResults;
    NodeList nodes;
    Document doc;
    static ServiceTasks task;
    String line;
    public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){

        Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;

    }


     private class ServiceTasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {

                            try {

                                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/example.xml");

                                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                                    line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                    line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                    line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
                                }
                            return null;


            }
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    if(mListener!=null)
        mListener.AsyncTaskDone();
    }


        } 

     public String getXML(){     

         return line;
    }

     public void executeXML(){
         task = new ServiceTasks();
         task.execute();
     }


}




  public class Main extends ListActivity implements ListenerToXML {

         String xml;
         static XMLfunctions funct;
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.listofcategories);
            funct = new XMLfunctions();
            funct.setListener(this);
            funct.executeXML();
.
.
.
}


            public void AsyncTaskDone() {
               //here you can get the results
            xml = funct.getXML();
            }
```

Comment: I've also called `funct.executeXML()' right? This executes the AsynTask, isn't it?

Comment: yes but this call is not blocking. It will execute doInBackground in a thread. So the results as i said are not available just after this call

Comment: But I have stored the string value that is evaluated in `DoInBackground` in `funct.line` itself! So can I not access it anywhere as `funct.line` after it is executed?

Incase you think I haven't got your point clearly, could you post the corrected code?

Comment: @Enigman check the edits on how to create a listener. although there are simpler ways

Comment: Hey thanks for the code update. Will check and get back to you!

Comment: `return pow("thanks",10000000);` It works=)

Can't upvote as I'm a newbie here and I don't have enough reputation. :(

Comment: hehe it is okay, stay @stackoverflow